# Keep proper time

Tags: idioms

What does "keep proper time" in the following sentence mean?

> I've needed a new one for ages- mine hasn't *kept proper time* since I dropped it in the bath.*

Comment: 'Keep proper time': (a) stop completely (b) gain (c) lose time (d) run backwards (e) stop for 20 minute intervals, then suddenly catch up (f) tell the time accurately. Guess which is the correct answer. (Or you could Google "keep proper time".) Admittedly, it's an odd (though very common) construction.

Comment: How in the name of goodness would a non-native speaker know that "keep time" is the usual formulation of what a timepiece does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Keep time"

is the usual formulation in English for what a watch does. (It possibly comes from "keep track of" time.)

For example, a computer: "does calculations." A truck "moves goods."  Photoshop "edits photos."  Insulation "stores heat."

What do watches "do"? They "keep time."

Note that indeed you have the English word **"timekeeper"**, OED says

> timekeeper |ˈtʌɪmkiːpə|
>   noun
>   1 a person who measures or records the amount of time taken, especially in a sports competition. timekeepers waited in the heavy rain for the teams to pass. official timekeepers.
>   2 [ usu. with adj. ] a person regarded as being punctual or not punctual: we were good timekeepers.
>   • a watch or clock regarded as recording time accurately or inaccurately: these watches are accurate timekeepers.
>   • archaic a clock.

So, a watch "keeps time."  You can insert any, uhh, adjective? in there **or at the end**; "keeps time badly" "keeps time cheaply" "keeps time horribly" "barely is able to keep time" "keeps proper time" "keeps great time" "keeps correct time" "keeps world time" "keeps satellite time", "keeps Hong Kong time" etc.

I think, the formulations where you put a word in the "middle" are, possibly, grammatically incorrect. And note that "keeps proper time" is about the only common such phrase. I have a feeling it's better to say "keeps time perfectly" or "keeps time correctly"

Then again, something like "atomic time" or "Sydney time" is indeed a two word phrase. Perhaps for that reason you can say "keeps Sydney time" or "keeps proper time".(

Answer (score 1):

It means that the watch he is using has not been working properly sincehe dropped it in the bath. That is, the clock did not reflect the accurate time.